# How to implement Curl effect in OpenAphide Application?

Tags: android

I have been continuously trying to customize OpenAphide project but Unable to achieve that,Actually I want to flip animation with curl Like Attached Image but I unable to troubleshoot that please anyone help me How can I achieve That.I have been used curl animation in android which is on code.google but that is not fullfill my need.Actually
need is there is curl in openAphide flip animation please anyone guide me.
                                                                          thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Did you solved your problem?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you check [this](https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/android-page-curl) one ?

In this example that will show curl animation in two different way like

- ListView
- LinearLayout

Check it once may be this will helpful to you.

Comment: I have check this,And In question I Have mension As well .Please help if you have done work on same.

Comment: where did you get a problem in this link?

Comment: not problem but wat to mixup of both mean that it will be like flip animation with curl but in curt it not fold from half .

Comment: ok @LOOSER  i had check it.that effect is work on half screen and next image or other control hind behind that if you drag the icon at right corner. but if you just click at that corner icon that will move full screen in curl effect . check it.

Comment: thanks for your responce,please check one time demo of openAphide I want curl in that demo ,its 2D example and when turn no back image shown

Comment: write openAphide on google or write how to make app like flipboard in stackoverflow

Comment: please share that link just copy and past here

Comment: http://openaphid.github.com/blog/2012/05/21/how-to-implement-flipboard-animation-on-android/

Comment: see curl effect and this effect both are different. so its batter that you ask other question so more experience developer can get main query and response to you.